# Notify user at particular battery level

Tags: c#, batterylevel

I need to to notify the user when the battery level is exact 20%. Currently I am using a `Timer` to check the `SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryLifePercent` status repeatedly in a fixed interval. Is there any better and efficient way to do it?

**Edit:** I want to make it work on laptops.

Comment: You didn't say what kind of device you're trying to work on. Is it a phone? Is it a laptop? What system do you target? We're not going to guess.

Comment: Depends on device and what are you using to get that `BatteryLifePercent` it is from `Systeminfo` or `PowerStatus` class or is it some custom 3rd party class or app? But there is nothing wrong with checking it with `Timer`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#, Constantly monitor battery level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832969/c-constantly-monitor-battery-level)

Answer (score 1):

This answer [C#, Constantly monitor battery level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832969/c-constantly-monitor-battery-level) proposes to register to the [`SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/net-monitor-power-status)-Event like this:

```
static void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Mode == Microsoft.Win32.PowerModes.StatusChange)
    {
        if (pw.BatteryLifeRemaining == 20)
        {
         //Do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```